# Custom validation attribute in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I have created a custom validaton attribute in asp.net MVC but it is not working. Constructor of validation class calls but `IsValid` function not calling on "Submit" button press. My Code is:

```
public class TestAttribute :ValidationAttribute
    {
        private new readonly string ErrorMessage;
        public TestAttribute(string ErrorMessage)
        {
            this.ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage;
        }

        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
           if(value!=null)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            return new ValidationResult(this.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

Usage:

```
 [Test("Error")]
 public string User_Pwd { get; set; } 



<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label class="control-label">Password</label>
              @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User_Pwd, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "User Password", @maxlength = "50", id = "txt_Pwd" })
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.User_Pwd)
         </div>
</div>
```

This is a sample code. Here constructor of Test class calls but `IsValid` function is not calling.

Comment: I dun understand, you want to call both the constructor and IsValid when calling the 'Submit' button? You need to provide more code.

Comment: The code you have shown works fine. What makes you think the `IsValid()` method is not called?

Comment: Are you expecting to see a client side validation error (and the submit will be cancelled)?

Comment: @StephenMuecke I am not getting error message on view, when I debug code then I observe that constructor is calling but IsValid function is not calling.

Comment: Yes, I want client side validation error.

Comment: To get client side validation, your `ValidationAttribute` must implement `IClientValidatable` and you need to write the associated client side scripts - refer [The Complete Guide To Validation In ASP.NET MVC 3 - Part 2](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, it works now. Thanks.